# Android "daily device installs" don't match payments

Tags: android, google-play

When I view my "daily device installs" in the Android Developer Console, the figures don't bear any resemblance to what Google is paying out.

Can anyone shed any light on this?  For example, for a day where I have 20 "daily device installs" according to Google, they only paid out for 9 app installs.  This is typical for me.  If I calculate the monthly figures, they are out by roughly the same percentage.

I noticed about 2 months back that Flurry was displaying many new users than I was getting paid for, so I wrote some fairly complicated custom anti-piracy code using the Google Library and disabled the old versions of the app.  This didn't fix the problem for even one day.

I would really like to know what's going on. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Does this include people who install and then remove an app before payment is taken? I think you're given 15 minutes grace.

Comment: That is correct.  But more than 50% of people using this grace period?  Probably not.

Also, the figures for the "free" version of the app match up nicely. It's just the paid "pro" version that doesn't match.

Comment: Maybe owner of the app that just reinstall or install on second device?

Answer (score 1):

This question got me thinking... so I went to check my charts and this is my theory:

Daily user installs definition is "the number of unique users who installed this app for the the first time during that day."
I think the key is "first time during that day", and not "first time ever"..
That means that it might be some old customer who uninstalled your app previously, or just flashed their phone to a new custom rom, and decided to install your app on that day for the first time. You could have 10 installs on that day but only 2 were new purchases.

I usually use the Revenue chart in Developer console instead, it seems to match closer to actual payment. Although the revenue for one particular day doesn't seem to match the google wallet payment on the same day, I observe a period of time say 20 days and the number does match, some days revenue is higher than payment and some days payment is higher than revenue. I guess this is due to the way credit card purchases are processed in different countries.. some countries take more days to process through (up to a few days).

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I also can't figure this out. My first thought was counting of pirated copies, but now I'm not so sure.

The order inbox is supposed to be showing all transactions, including user cancels/returns and payment declined's.

On March 19 I had 592 active installs. That day I had 2 good sales, and 4 cancels (groan) in the order inbox. But stats say 13 users installed that day and 10 un-installed.

My app has a lot of custom ROM users, so perhaps it's at least partly due to ROM upgrades ? And/or the fact that a single user can have multiple devices ? (Despite these being user stats.)

That same day shows 42 device installs and 13 uninstalls.So a delta of 3 users versus 29 devices ???

The definitions for daily user installs/uninstalls seem symmetrical and the former says "for the first time":

"Daily user installs - the number of unique users who installed this app for the the FIRST TIME during that day.
Daily user uninstalls - the number of unique users who uninstalled the app from all devices during that day."

And this, "new devices... for the first time":

"Daily device installs - the number of new devices on which the app was installed for the first time during that day.
Daily device uninstalls - the number of unique devices which uninstalled the app in the past day."

I can only think there's a large piracy problem being counted here, or the stats or their definitions are wrong. Or my logic just can't grok it.